# Can WatiN download files without requiring focus?

Tags: c#, automation, focus, download, watin

I use WatiN to automate file transfers (EDI transactions) to/from multiple websites, unfortunately FTP or anything more automation-friendly is not an option. For downloads, I use variations of this example:

```
FileDownloadHandler download = new FileDownloadHandler(fullFilename);
using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, download))
{
    lnkFile.ClickNoWait();

    download.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
    download.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(150);
}
```

This works fine, the only problem is that it requires focus. It's not uncommon for there to be dozens of files to download which can take awhile to complete. I run it in a remote session so my machine isn't unusable, but if there's any way to remove the need for focus it'd be convenient.

Comment: Could you explain what the lnkFile should be? Thanks!

Comment: lnkFile is a Link, in this case the one that needs to be clicked to initiate the file download. Say your instance of WatiN.Core.IE is called ie, you could instantiate lnkFile as: lnkFile = ie.Link(Find.ById("download"));

Comment: I have setup a link file as you suggested but it still doesn't download the file in IE9. Any other ideas? Should I use something other than "download" in my Link file? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used WatiN in awhile, but I've seen mailing list emails saying that file downloads aren't working in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Watin, I would use the WebClient class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Should be able to upload and download files using that class.

Comment: I just looked into this but can't seem to find any means of handling file download dialogs - the DownloadFile method would work fine but the download links provided on the sites aren't direct links to the files.

Comment: Oh, the links fire some JS and you need to take further action?  That does make things quite a bit more complex.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately that's the case. WatiN's pretty versatile for all my purposes, it's just the minor hangup of the focus.

Comment: I think you can inject javascript using watin, so can you inject something to set the focus on the control you need?

Comment: I probably could have worded the question better - the issue is not that WatiN won't focus on a required control to download a file, it's that it does require focus to download a file and ties up the machine for the duration of the transfers.